# Count click on links with mysql and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

What i have:

```
<body>
    <a href="'.$a.'">'.$name_a.'</a>
    <a href="'.$b.'">'.$name_b.'</a>
    <a href="'.$c.'">'.$name_c.'</a>
</body>
```

a,b,c are external link, like spotify/youtube or whatever. I'd like to check "what users prefer". 
I take links from a mysql table. My idea is to add columns in mysql table to get this scheme

```
|   links   |   counters for each links     |
|           |                               |
|           |                               |
|           |                               |
```

But it seems not so optimized.
Moreover I don't know how to call php function to add +1 to the counter when link is clicked. Any ideas? Other more efficient strategies? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should set up your tables something like this

```
+---------------+  +-------------------------+
|     CLICKS    |  |       LINKS             |
+------+--------+  +------+------------------+ 
|  ID  | LINKID |  |  ID  |       LINK       |
+------+--------+  +------+------------------+
|  1   |   12   |  |  12  +  http://link.com |
+ -----+--------+  + -----+------------------+
```

Then you can just do count(*) where ID=linkid to get click count. And its easier to check if a user have already clicked etc if you want that. Just add another column and track ip etc. When it comes to adding the click you can do it with a simple ajax request. Something like below.

```
<body>
    <a href="'.$a.'" onclick='addClick(12);'>'.$name_a.'</a>
    <a href="'.$b.'" onclick='addClick(13);'>'.$name_b.'</a>
    <a href="'.$c.'" onclick='addClick(14);'>'.$name_c.'</a>
</body> 


function addClick(id) {
    let linkId = id;
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "addClick.php",
        data: {
            "linkId": linkId,
        },
        success() {
            // Update your page count here
        },
    });
}

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['linkId']) {
          // Mysql query
    } 
?>
```

Comment: I don't know much about ajax, what is addClick.php? does ajax redirect to that page? after success(){ what i have to do?}

Comment: yes, the ajax call will do a post request to addClick.php with the values you set in data: { }. So make a file called addClick.php or what ever you want, just make sure its the same in url. And do isset($_POST['linkId']); Everything you put inside the data block will be sent as a post variable. So if you etc do "someOtherVar" : someValue. addClick.php will also have access to $_POST['someOtherVar'] with the value of someValue. You will need jQuery for the above ajax snippet to work. https://jquery.com/ You dont have to do anything in the success block, but you can update your html element etc.

Comment: Thanks, I put "counter.php" to post method and put PHP script but it seems not fill $Post...ideas?

Comment: Have you added onclick='addClick(linkId);' on your links? Are you checking the correct post variable? left side of the data block in the ajax call have to be exact match etc "linkId" : urlId will be $_POST['linkId']. If you use Chrome you can open the dev tools window navigate to the network tab and click on the counter.php file in the list. Click on the header tab and navigate to the bottom and you can see the post values sent with the request. Make sure you have the dev tools window open before running the ajax call else counter.php wont display in the network list.

Comment: Ok I make it works! There's still a little problems...if i try to redirect to an external website it seems skipping onclick. I mean if i use <a onclick> without href all Ok but if I use <a href="" onclick=""> it is skipped... may i have to delay redirect?

Comment: It would be a problem to redirect straight away. You could try to delay the redirect but I would rather just use target="_blank" on the href. That way the user gets to the clicked link when they click but, your webpage can also handle the click and add 1 to the count

Answer (score 3):

This is 2 parts: Code and Data

## Code

You have two popular options: AJAX or Redirect.

With AJAX you can basically intercept user clicks and send the data (which link was clicked, user session etc) to your server and then let the user continue continue after getting a response from the server or a timeout (in case the server is too slow or fails).

With a Redirect tracker, you basically have an url/file infront of the links, so you can run some server code before redirecting to the actual url. Something like:

```
https://<your-website>.com/tracker.php?url=<original-url>
```

## Database

If you want to keep it really simple, you could just increment a column for every link in your database that is being tracked when visited.
The above is very limited if you want more data about the user visiting (such as IP, Session etc.), so another option is to use a related table that stores the id of the link and other user data/timestamps.

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/o8nRKZtzhq8cTpQvknhq3S/0